# How to use Web activity in Azure Data Factory to count the total number of pages in source data?

Tags: azure-data-factory, amazon-data-pipeline

I am doing REST API call to get source data which is JSON and file size is around 1GB. I would like to use pagination concept. I see in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/59467/how-to-pass-pagination-rules-during-a-rest-api-cal.html?childToView=256118#answer-256118 where it uses Web activity to get the total page. But how? any advise!
My sink is COSMOS DB

Comment: Are you writing any custom code to pull that data from API? Like a C# code or something? and then calling that in your web activity?

Comment: Nope. I am not writing any custom code. In the link I referenced, it says I can do web activity followed by Copy tool. But I am not able to replicate their logic how web activity help us to count the total pages.

Comment: I think we only can get the total pages from API.

Answer (score 0):

According to your link, I think  we only can make a web call to find out the total pages. In other words, the total pages is from your REST API. Then we can use an Array type variable to store the response.